# How can I modify CoreDNS configmap before I bootstrap the cluster using kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I need to build my on-prem Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.

Since my environment has no DNS, I have to modify a configmap of CoreDNS so that it doesn't contain a forwarding section.

After deploying the cluster, I can edit the configmap using `kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system`, but it takes a bit of time for CoreDNS to work properly after the modification that might be a problem for my production environment.

Is it possible to edit this configmap before the execution of `kubeadm init`?

Comment: What is the kubernetes version you are using?

Comment: I'm using v.1.22.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to find a solution with `kubeadm init`, there is a similar issue in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675972/kubernetes-how-to-edit-coredns-corefile-configmap) for your reference.

However, consider using helm to your on-prem cluster and using Helm Charts Hooks. There are many useful annotations and one of them `pre-install` could be your solution.

The steps:

- [Install Helm](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-helm) to your on-prem cluster.
- [Write a Hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) with `pre-install` annotation
- [Install CoreDNS using Helm](https://github.com/coredns/helm) and its Hook

I've given short guide with the useful links to avoid copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using Helm.